# Can we force the browser to use a custom object as window object while executing js code

Tags: javascript, proxy, window

When we set or read any variable, the browser reads it from or sets it to the **window**

```js
a = 10; // this is evaluated as "window.a = 10"
console.log(a) // this is evaluated as "console.log(window.a)"
```

But how can we override that behaviour and force it to use any other object (actually I want to be able to do it with a Proxy) instead of **window**.

```js
const proxy = new Proxy({}, {
  get(prop, val, reciever){
    return [prop, val, reciever]
  }
}) // Suppose I have defined a proxy
a = 10 // how can I force the browser to evaluate this as "proxy.a = 10"
```

Is there a way to do this in JavaScript without using any external libraries?

Comment: This isn’t possible. The global object cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Can we do any kinds of trick?

Comment: Let's say the code, whose global object I want to change is put inside a function, then is there any way to achieve this result?

Comment: I guess you can parse the code into an AST, replace all reference to `window`, then compile it back to a code which you will evaluate.

Comment: @ITgoldman This may help, I must try, Thank you